# Can't re-install OS on Asus Eee PC 1018P

Tags: installation, eee-pc, windows-installation

My friend has an Asus Eee PC 1018P. It has no CD/DVD drive (neither does he have a USB CD/DVD drive).

The OS wasn't working fine, so we decided to restore the system using the provided OS backup from HD. But mid way through the installation it was interrupted and the computer was restarted (not a hardware or software issue – *we* did it).

Now we cannot run the backup and we also tried to install Windows 7 through USB, but as soon as we start to install the OS, it says that some device driver is missing. It turns out that the OS needs a USB device driver to continue. It has USB 3.0 – maybe that's why the OS needs the driver.

I tried disabling 3.0 and enabling 2.0 but then it does not boot from USB drive for some reason.

We are stuck with this. The backup doesn't run and when booting from USB, it says that it needs a device driver.

Anyone has any idea what we could do?

Comment: Hi, You have one USB 2.0 on the left side and it works

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to boot an OS from a SD card? In most case, the SD card reader is connected to a USB 2.0 controller.

Most USB 3.0 controllers (all of them?) need a dedicated driver to be installed. Therefore, another solution for reinstalling the OS would be to download the driver on a different machine and slipstream it into the image file. Form what i read on google in the few seconds I spent on the search, [vlite](http://www.vlite.net/) seems be able to do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

If the bios has an option to boot to the recovery partition, just format the OS partitions from linux live usb and start over.

Comment: I cannot find any such option. The main thing is that I can boot from usb but the os needs device driver.